# Is there any way to know that device mode is dark or light? in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to change the app color by mode of device whether if it is dark or light.

But I don't know how to check that my device is in dark mode or in light mode.

Please advice something.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the `Appearance` module, via

```js
import { Appearance } from 'react-native';

const colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme();
if (colorScheme === 'dark') {
  // Use dark color scheme
}
```

You can also check whether the user has changed those settings by adding a listener like such:

```js
static addChangeListener(listener)
```

Look [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appearance) for the documentation.

Comment: it always appears the light mode.. can you please check here? https://snack.expo.dev/@john.ocean/grounded-kiwi

Comment: It appears on dark mode for me. Probably because I have my browser in dark mode. Try changing your browser appearance

Comment: Tried it but backgroundcolor still not changeing

Comment: @JohnOcean it looks like when debugging the app, getColorScheme will return always light